# Remove items from dynamic array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a dynamic array (chat messages), like

```
{
 id:1,
 message: bla-bla
},
{
 id:2,
 message: bla-bla
},
{
 id:1,
 message: bla-bla
},
{
 id:1,
 message: bla-bla
},
{
 id:3,
 message: bla-bla
},
{
 id:4,
 message: bla-bla
}
```

How to leave in array only items with `id:1`, or remove all items where `id` not `1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of `.filter()` and only return items where the id is equal to 1.

```
var newArr = yourArray.filter(function(item) {
  return item.id === 1
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0avdpb2c/)

And for more info and the `.filter()` shim for older browsers - [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: At the end point I need to have an array with items where id == 1

Comment: @Serhiog.Lazin My bad, i've made the amendment

Comment: Thanks very much! Simple and amazing!